# How do I change the url hover link color in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm using the latest version of Notepad++ (7.6.3), and I would like to change the color of the hyperlinks when I hover over them.

I found this [wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Clickable_Links) about clickable links, but it seems the information is out of date. I cannot find `URL Hovered` under `Global Styles`.

Comment: It's [still there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBL1a.jpg), but any color change needs a restart of Notepad++.

Comment: @harrymc - It seems that `URL Hovered` is style dependent. I have the solarized style enabled, and the option doesn't exist. If I switch to the default style, it shows up.

Comment: You might try to copy the "URL Hovered" line from the file `stylers.xml` in the folder `%APPDATA%\Notepad++` to the file `Solarized (Dark).xml` (or Light). It's the last style in the file.

Answer (score 1):

- Macro Method: Here is the [macro method](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Clickable_Links) to change the color of clickable links. Open Notepad++ installation folder. Find **shortcuts.xml** file. Open that file in any text editor, except Notepad++. Otherwise restart Notepad++ every after changing color. Add these lines in between `<Macros>` tag.

```xml
<Macro name="setHotForeground" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="100">
    <Action type="0" message="2410" wParam="1" lParam="your_colour" sParam=""/>
</Macro>
```

Choose your color and add it in `lParam=your_colour` attribute. The color is in RRGGBB hex format. For example, this is what looks like after changing:

```xml
<NotepadPlus>
    <InternalCommands />
        <Macros>
            <Macro name="setHotForeground" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="100">
                <Action type="0" message="2410" wParam="1" lParam="008080" sParam=""/>
            </Macro>
        </Macros>
```

Here `Key="100"` means <kbd>Numpad 4</kbd>. So the key combination to activate the color change is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 4</kbd>.

---

- Edit theme: If you are using your own customized theme another way is to edit the theme XML file. Open the XML file of the current theme in themes folder. Find the `<GlobalStyles>` tag. Write this tag in it:

```xml
<WidgetStyle name="URL hovered" styleID="0" fgColor="your_color" fontStyle="0" bgColor="your_color" />
```

Here `fgColor` is ForeGround Color and `bgColor` is BackGround Color. The colors are also in hex RRGGBB format. Choose your own color.

Answer (score 0):

The better answer for macro solution I got is in this link
https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/c4ed5b69/
there the color foreground in not in the way RRGGBB is a number
because with RRGGBB format do not run for me, and notepad++ overwrite it.
This is for green Color, just the color that i wanted because I have
black background and blue is dark, is using keypad 5

```
<Macro name="colorAHSgreen" Ctrl="Yes" Alt="Yes" Shift="No" Key="101">
<Action type="0" message="2410" wParam="1" lParam="65280" sParam=""/> 
</Macro>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "Quick Color Picker for Notepad++". You double-click on the hex color and a color-picker pops up as well as a preview. Another cool thing is that it provides a few more colors that match the "theme" if you will.

[Here is the link Quick Color Picker](https://github.com/nulled666/nppqcp)

SIDE NOTE: There used to be a feature or plugin, until very recently, that actually highlighted the text of the hex code with its color. It came out of nowhere after an N++ update and then it disappeared after another one. Can't figure out how to enable it again.

Answer (score -1):

The comment by @harrymc is correct and deserves to be accepted as the correct answer. Here it is for anyone else's attention:

> You might try to copy the "URL Hovered" line from the file `stylers.xml` in the folder `%APPDATA%\Notepad++` to the file `Solarized (Dark).xml` (or Light). It's the last style in the file.

Comment: A professional would explain why they disagree and downvote an answer. The above answer did work for me and will most likely work for anyone else on Windows. Again the credit for the answer does not go to me, but it should not be downvoted either. People looking for an answer would be misguided by the downvote. I have been looking for an answer to this problem for several months and @harrymc's comments were the ultimate solution. In particular, the other answer provided here, despite being highly verbose, did not work for me.